# How can I access the content within the tags in an ASP.NET CORE ViewComponent?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I create a ViewComponent that renders some HTML on a Razor page. Looks like this:

```
<vc:Blockheader button-text="Create new skill" block-title="@ViewData["Title"]">
    hello
</vc:Blockheader>
```

How do I access the value **hello** from the ViewComponent class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have access to this content. The parameters to the view component are passed as attributes (in lower kebab case) so you can add an additional parameter to `Invoke` method.

Example:

```
public class BlockHeader : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(string buttonText, string blockTitle, string message)
    {
        // ...
        return View<string>(message);
    }
}
```

Invoking a view component as a Tag Helper:

```
<vc:block-header button-text="param1Value" block-title="param2Value" message="hello">    
</vc:block-header>
```